# How to get total count in root.iter() in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am XML file, there are 10 sub-children (same hierarchy) of root, having the name 'testCase'

I am not able to figure out the following: 
Firstly, I am doing the following to get all the sub-children:

```
for testCase in root.iter('testCase'):
```

1. I need to get some attribute from the last sub-child 'testCase'. But how do i know that it is the last 'testCase'. Is there a way to count them?
2. Also, is there a way to access the nth sub-child without having to go through the iter()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning this type of manipulations, you should use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp), which is a common and simple way to browse XML trees. I don't think the standard Python ElementTree support XPath, but [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) does (very commonly used as well), here is an example:

Get last child:

```
>>> text = """<Root>
    <Child name="child1" />
    <Child name="child2" />
    <Child name="child3" />
    <Child name="child4" />
    <Child name="child5" />
</Root>"""
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring(text)
>>> last_tag = root.xpath('/Root/Child[last()]')[0]
>>> last_tag.attrib['name']
'child5'
```

Direct access to element number #n:

```
>>> tag3 = root.xpath('/Root/Child[3]')[0]
>>> tag3.attrib['name']
'child3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following sample. See the output below. It shows what was used as the content of the `my.xml`. The element behaves as a list of children (i.e. it can also be iterated). There are functions and iterators to get all wanted elements in a document order independently on their position (i.e. it does not matter how deep they are, whose children etc.). The `element.attrib` behaves as a dictionary of attributes. The standard `xml.etree.ElementTree` supports also the subset of XPath -- see at the end:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('my.xml')
root = tree.getroot()     # the root element of the tree

et.dump(root)             # here is how the input file looks inside

# Any element behaves as a list of children. This way, the last child
# of the list can be accessed via negative index.
print '-------------------------------------------'
print root[-1]

# Here is the content.
print '-------------------------------------------'
et.dump(root[-1])

# If the elements could be not direct children, you can use findall('tag') to 
# get the list of the elements. Then you access it again as the last element
# of the list
print '-------------------------------------------'
lst = root.findall('testCase')
et.dump(lst[-1])

# The number of the 'testCase' elements is simply the length of the list.
print '-------------------------------------------'
print 'Num. of test cases:', len(lst)

# The elem.iter('tag') works similarly. But if you want the last element,
# you must know when the element is the last one. It means you have to 
# loop through all of them anyway.
print '-------------------------------------------'
last = None  # init
for e in root.iter('testCase'):
    last = e

et.dump(last)

# The attributes of the elements take the form of the dictinary .attrib.
print '-------------------------------------------'
print last.attrib
print last.attrib['name']

# The standard xml.etree.ElementTree supports a subset of XPath. You can use
# it if you are familiar with XPath.
print '-------------------------------------------'
third = root.find('.//testCase[3]')
et.dump(third)

# ... including the last() function. For more complex cases, use lxml
# as pointed out by Emmanuel.
print '-------------------------------------------'
last = root.find('.//testCase[last()]')
et.dump(last)
```

It prints the following on my console:

```
    c:\tmp\___python\Sunny\so12669404>python a.py
<root>
  <testCase name="a" />
  <testCase name="b" />
  <testCase name="c" />
  <testCase name="d" />
</root>
-------------------------------------------
<Element 'testCase' at 0x231a630>
-------------------------------------------
<testCase name="d" />
-------------------------------------------
<testCase name="d" />
-------------------------------------------
Num. of test cases: 4
-------------------------------------------
<testCase name="d" />
-------------------------------------------
{'name': 'd'}
d
-------------------------------------------
<testCase name="c" />

-------------------------------------------
<testCase name="d" />
```